# modular arthimetic equations. is there a different way to do this?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The problem states:  When a group is marching 4 people abreast, there is one left over.   When they march 5 abreast, there is 2 left over.   When they march 7 abreast, there is 3 left.  How many are there in the group?

here's what I did.   Define $x$ to be the number of people in the group.

then $1\equiv$ x mod 4, $3\equiv$ x mod 7, and $2\equiv$ x mod 5.

then I created a set for each case and found the intersection.

1 mod 4 = {1,5,9,13,17,21...}
2 mod 5 = {2,7,12,17,22...}
3 mod 7 = {3,10,17,24...}

so we see that 17 is a particular solution $x_0$.   so all solutions take the form of $x_0 + 140n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ as $140 = lcm(7,5,4)$.

my question is... is there a better way to solve this without visual inspection of the sets for my initial $x_0$?

Comment: @Piman.   thanks.   I didn't know that the Lcm was the connection there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) will do what you want.  In your case, it would find a number $a$ that is $1 \pmod 4$ and $0 \pmod 7$ and another one $b$ that is $0 \pmod 4$ and $1 \pmod 7$.  In this case $a=21 \pmod {28}, b=8 \pmod{ 28}$  and your $x\equiv a+3b \equiv 21+24 \equiv 17 \pmod {28}$.  Another go around will incorporate the $2 \pmod 5$ condition.  For small numbers inspection is easier.